# Setup version for module '***' is not specified

Tags: module, magento-2.1, error, installation

Recently I have create one module. but after install its generate following  error

```
Setup version for module '***' is not specified
```

**Here Composer file**

```
{
    "name": "dd/module-productinquiry",
    "description": "DD productinquiry",
    "require": {
      "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-contact": "100.0.*"    
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "DD/Productinquiry"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "dd\\productinquiry\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**Registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'DD_Productinquiry',
    __DIR__
);
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="DD_Productinquiry" schema_version="2.0.1" setup_version="2.0.1"/> 
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace your composer file like this.

```
Composer file.

{
    "name": "dd/module-productinquiry",
    "description": "DD productinquiry",
    "require": {
      "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-contact": "100.0.*"    
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "DD/Productinquiry"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "dd\\productinquiry\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

And your `module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="DD_Productinquiry" setup_version="2.0.1" schema_version="2.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Comment: Yes its working